# Apexcharts.js How I can change the font color of bar (value of series)?

Tags: apexcharts

Please help me to hide or change font color of these values of bar.
Is this possible or not?

[image: These values]

```
var options = {
          series: [{
          name: 'Worked hours',
          data: [44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43, 20],
          color: '#806CAF',
        }, {
          name: 'Dle hours',
          data: [21, 7, 25, 13, 22, 8, 5],
          color: "#F46646"
        }],
          chart: {
          type: 'bar',
          height: 240,
          stacked: true,
          toolbar: {
            show: true
          },
          zoom: {
            enabled: true
          }
        },
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom',
              offsetX: -10,
              offsetY: 0
            }
          }
        }],
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            position: 'bottom',
            horizontal: false,
            borderRadius: 2,
            dataLabels: {
              total: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: '12px',
                  fontWeight: 600
                },
              }
            }
          },
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          categories: ['01/01/2011 GMT', '01/02/2011 GMT', '01/03/2011 GMT', '01/04/2011 GMT',
            '01/05/2011 GMT', '01/06/2011 GMT'],
          labels: {
            show: true,
            rotate: -45,
            rotateAlways: false,
            hideOverlappingLabels: true,
            showDuplicates: false,
            trim: false,
            minHeight: undefined,
            maxHeight: 120,
            style: {
              color: '#363240',
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: '12px',
              fontWeight: 600,
              cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
          }
          }
        },
        colors: ["#000000"],
        yaxis: {
          type: 'numeric',
          categories: ['01ч', '02ч', '03ч', '04ч'],
          labels: {
            show: true,
            rotateAlways: false,
            hideOverlappingLabels: true,
            showDuplicates: false,
            trim: false,
            minHeight: undefined,
            maxHeight: 120,
            style: {
              color: '#9E99AB',
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: '12px',
              fontWeight: 500,
              cssClass: 'apexcharts-yaxis-label'
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          show: false
        },
        fill: {
          opacity: 1
        },
        grid: {
          show: true,
          borderColor: '#F3F2F4',
          opacity: '1'
        }
        }

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart-column"), options);
        chart.render();
```

I tried to change colors using:

style: {
color: '#363240'
}

but for the plotOptions it turned out to change only the total value of the column

total: {
enabled: true,
style: {}

How I can change font style of value?

UPD: I was able to do this through opacity:

plotOptions: {
bar: {
distributed: false,
horizontal: false,
dataLabels: {
position: 'bottom',
total: {
enabled: true,
style: {
color: '#363240',
fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
fontSize: '12px',
fontWeight: 600
}
}
},
}
},
dataLabels: {
enabled: true,
style: {
colors: ['rgba(0,0,0,0)']
}
},

Answer (score 1):

inside chartOptions you have dataLabels, there you can just disable these:

```
dataLabels: {
 enabled: false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var options = {
          series: [{
          name: 'Worked hours',
          data: [44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43, 20],
          color: '#806CAF',
        }, {
          name: 'Dle hours',
          data: [21, 7, 25, 13, 22, 8, 5],
          color: "#F46646"
        }],
          chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            height: 240,
            stacked: true,
            toolbar: {
                show: true
            },
            zoom: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
                style: {
                    colors: ["#212529"]
                }
        },
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom',
              offsetX: -10,
              offsetY: 0
            }
          }
        }],
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            position: 'bottom',
            horizontal: false,
            borderRadius: 2,
            dataLabels: {
              total: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: '12px',
                  fontWeight: 600
                },
              }
            }
          },
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          categories: ['01/01/2011 GMT', '01/02/2011 GMT', '01/03/2011 GMT', '01/04/2011 GMT',
            '01/05/2011 GMT', '01/06/2011 GMT'],
          labels: {
            show: true,
            rotate: -45,
            rotateAlways: false,
            hideOverlappingLabels: true,
            showDuplicates: false,
            trim: false,
            minHeight: undefined,
            maxHeight: 120,
            style: {
              color: '#363240',
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: '12px',
              fontWeight: 600,
              cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
          }
          }
        },
        colors: ["#000000"],
        yaxis: {
          type: 'numeric',
          categories: ['01ч', '02ч', '03ч', '04ч'],
          labels: {
            show: true,
            rotateAlways: false,
            hideOverlappingLabels: true,
            showDuplicates: false,
            trim: false,
            minHeight: undefined,
            maxHeight: 120,
            style: {
              color: '#9E99AB',
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: '12px',
              fontWeight: 500,
              cssClass: 'apexcharts-yaxis-label'
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          show: false
        },
        fill: {
          opacity: 1
        },
        grid: {
          show: true,
          borderColor: '#F3F2F4',
          opacity: '1'
        }
        }

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart-column"), options);
        chart.render();
```

Comment: Just add
dataLabels: {
                style: {
                    colors: ["#212529"]
                }
        },

Comment: dataLabels: {
                style: {
                    colors: ["#212529"]
                }
        },

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include your comments. Otherwise, they really get lost behind this big code listing, and it’s hard to understand what’s changed.